# COUNT with condition of group by having in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I know for every `Track2` how many times it appears?

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
    SELECT Track2 
    FROM Knowledge4All..AllMembers
    WHERE YEAR(DateCreated) = '2020' 
      AND UserSiteLastLogin IS NULL 
    GROUP BY Track2 
    HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Comment: Just add `count(*)` into your `select` statement - unless I'm missing something?

Comment: Using three part names is a bad habit that can lead to many problems - do not do this if you have no particular reason to do so. In addition, best practice is to ALWAYS specify the column list in an insert statement to avoid issues when the schema changes. And start using statement terminators - eventually they will be required.

Comment: `YEAR()` returns an `INT` value - so in your comparison, you **MUST NOT** put the value you compare to in single quotes - use `WHERE YEAR(DateCreated)  = 2020`  instead to do a *proper*, numeric comparison

Comment: @marc_s Better yet, get a sargeable lookup (ie. use the index) by doing this instead: `DateCreated >= '2020-01-01' AND DateCreated < '2021-01-01'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO #Temp
SELECT T.Track2 ,COUNT(*) AS CountForTrack2 FROM  YourTable AS T
WHERE YEAR(T.DateCreated) = 2020 AND  T.UserSiteLastLogin IS NULL 
GROUP BY T.Track2
HAVING COUNT(*) > 2
```

Be careful :

**COUNT(*)** will count all the rows in the table, including NULL values.
On the other hand, **COUNT(column name)** will count all the rows in the specified column while excluding NULL values.

You can also use [ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) :

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Track2,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [YourIDColumn]) AS rn
    FROM    YourTable
    WHERE YEAR(DateCreated) = 2020 AND  UserSiteLastLogin IS NULL 
)
INSERT INTO #Temp (Track2,CountForTrack2)
SELECT Track2,rn FROM CTE
WHERE rn>2
```